# Can a if statement save memory instead of applying value everytime?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management

First of all sorry for the shady question name I just didn't know how to call it, also sorry if for that same reason I wasn't able to find an answer.

It's pretty simple though, look at this everyday code :

```
value = x * y;
```

Let's imagine this code is called every frame, I want to make sure value is equal to something.
My question is : Would it be more profitable to write :

```
if(value != x * y)value = x * y;
```

I'm just wondering.
Wild guess is that it saves memory as long as the value is okay but takes twice as much when the value must be set.

Any info ?

Comment: What language/system are you using?

Comment: Added AS3 as tag, didn't know it was so relevant. Compiling with AIR, aiming iPads.

Comment: It almost feels like you're serving two purposes with these code snippets.  Two multiplication operations is twice as expensive as one.  What do you want to check against before assigning `value`?

Comment: Just to be sure, will x and y have just simple coordinate values? If so, I don't think this will any difference on memory, and the processing cost of assignment is likely to be so small that it can't be noticed. I haven't studied this issue closely enough to say with any certainty though, so I leave it to someone more confident to answer.

Comment: Just wondering if changing the value of value takes more memory than the multiplication itself, in which case code#2 would be better because it does not change the value on every frame.

Comment: Not clear on how you think it would save memory. If you assign a new value to a variable, it 'replaces' that value. So what memory is being saved/lost in that situation? Are you inquiring about performance difference ?

Comment: In any case the slight difference wouldn't really be relevant, but I'm just curious.

Comment: I'm not talking about memory in term of quantity but in term of speed. Maybe I used the wrong tag.

Comment: And to answer to BrianDHall ; x and y are just numbers, it's an out of context question.

Comment: If you are talking about performance, why not benchmark it ? If you are searching to optimize at this level, my suggestion is that you are likely focusing on the wrong area for optimization as it's gotta be massively minute unless you are dealing with an extremely large quantity of iterations per frame of this computation.

Comment: Like I said in the comments of the answer, let's just call it OCD. I'm aware it's not even really relevant at that point.

Comment: Haha, I hear ya. I think the fact that I've engaged, is just as much an indication of OCD.

Comment: The way this is usually handled it to just make `value` a setter that does nothing if the incoming value is not different than what's already stored in the private/protected representation.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship A setter wouldn't improve the performance, which is at the core of his question. He wasn't asking how to best implement a check, he's asking if the code executes faster or not with the check.

Comment: Yes, that _is_ why I used a comment, not an answer. However, it would still be more performant, because you'd only be multiplying once rather than twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning a value is generally faster, unless the assignment is processed via setter function, which can have a long overhead due to extra alterations being made to retain data integrity. So, if your target is a variable, or a simple property of a class (that is, it's not described via `public function set theProperty(value:SomeType):void` ) then it's faster to just assign, otherwise it's better to check first, but this is commonly done within the setter function.

Answer (score 1):

I ran tests here : 
http://jsperf.com/if-or-force-value

Random values : Assigning every time is better 
► Obviously since the if is useless (Will always return true)

Constant values : Assigning every time is better
► Not what I thought would happen but it seems that assigning a value is quicker to compute than an if statement.

Again I said as3, those tests are javascript, it might differ, but I'd be surprised.

Comment: You are not assigning a value to another, you are assigning a value to a variable.

Comment: Dude I'm french give me a chance. * Edited *

Comment: Sorry, do you want me to edit your answer ? The goal of this site is to have correct information.

Comment: I'd suggest using the word "quicker" in place of "easier". But I'm done here. cheers